# SPOE and modsecurity contrib Failed to decode HELLO frame

Tags: haproxy, mod-security

I'm compile modsec as described in the instructions contib/modsec/README, but have the next errors:

```
# /usr/local/bin/modsecurity -n 4 -d -f /etc/haproxy/waf/modsecurity.conf
1534409877.286475 [00] ModSecurity for nginx (STABLE)/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
1534409877.286555 [00] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.8"; loaded version="1.4.8"
1534409877.286577 [00] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.32 "; loaded version="8.32 2012-11-30"
1534409877.286593 [00] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.0.4"
1534409877.286610 [00] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
1534409877.286723 [00] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call: "2.9.2,nginx,1.4.8/1.4.8,8.32/8.32 2012-11-30,(null),2.9.1,4c3b0f175f079eaa4dd15b6eaef7a8207e809bb8"
1534409877.494433 [00] ModSecurity: StatusEngine call successfully sent. For more information visit: http://status.modsecurity.org/
1534409877.495333 [00] Worker 01 initialized
1534409877.495453 [01] Worker ready to process client messages
1534409877.495499 [00] Worker 02 initialized
1534409877.495514 [02] Worker ready to process client messages
1534409877.495767 [00] Worker 03 initialized
1534409877.495817 [03] Worker ready to process client messages
1534409877.495925 [00] Worker 04 initialized
1534409877.495958 [00] Server is ready [fragmentation=false - pipelining=false - async=false - debug=true - max-frame-size=16384]
1534409877.495961 [04] Worker ready to process client messages
1534409881.192419 [00] <1> New Client connection accepted and assigned to worker 01
1534409881.192511 [01] <1> read_frame_cb
1534409881.192596 [01] <1> New Frame of 129 bytes received
1534409881.192606 [01] <1> Decode HAProxy HELLO frame
1534409881.192613 [01] Failed to decode HELLO frame
1534409881.192617 [01] <1> Encode Agent DISCONNECT frame
1534409881.192626 [01] <1> Disconnect status code : 10
1534409881.192630 [01] <1> Disconnect message : fragmentation not supported
1534409881.192648 [01] <1> write_frame_cb
1534409881.192689 [01] <1> Frame of 58 bytes send
1534409881.192695 [01] <1> Release client
1534409882.497134 [01] 0 clients connected
1534409882.497174 [02] 0 clients connected
1534409882.497197 [04] 0 clients connected
1534409882.497185 [03] 0 clients connected
^C1534409885.480782 [00] Stopping the server
```

Has anyone encountered a similar one?

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since this questions was posted.
IMHO the error happens because of SPOP protocol.

```
SPOP v2 works with HAProxy 1.8.10 and newer.
SPOP v1 works with HAProxy up to 1.8.9.
```

```
[Solution]
Upgrade haproxy to 1.8.10 or higher
```

Hope it helps somebody.